# Is there a way to resolve 'cannot find import statement outside a module' in nextjs?

Tags: unit-testing, next.js, jestjs, babeljs, es6-modules

I am using nextjs and installed jest with Babel to do unit testing.

When I run npm test it gives me below error of 'import'
FAIL  **tests**/pages/index.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

/Users/alex/Desktop/test/tech-blog-web/node_modules/github-slugger/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { regex } from './regex.js'
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import React from 'react';
> 2 | import { slug } from "github-slugger";
    | ^
```

Most of my files are .js extension with a few of .jsx extension

I tried adding type:module in my package.json and changing my files name to .mjs but still face this error.

Below is my jest.config.js

```
      module.exports = {

      collectCoverage: true,
```

// on node 14.x coverage provider v8 offers good speed and more or less good report

```
  coverageProvider: 'v8',

  coverageReporters: ['json', 'html'],

  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',

  collectCoverageFrom: [

'**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',

'!**/*.d.ts',

'!**/node_modules/**',

'!<rootDir>/out/**',

'!<rootDir>/.next/**',

'!<rootDir>/*.config.js',

'!<rootDir>/coverage/**',
```

],

```
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",

  moduleNameMapper: {

"\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy",

// Handle module aliases

'^@layouts/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/layouts/$1',

'^@components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/layouts/components/$1',

'^@partials/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/layouts/partials/$1',

'^@shortcodes/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/layouts/shortcodes/$1',

'^@config/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/config/$1',

'^@json/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/json/$1',

'^@hooks/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/hooks/$1',

'^@lib/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/lib/$1',
```

},

```
  transform: {

// "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",

// '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',

// '^.+\\.js?$': 'babel-jest',

// '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',

// '^(github-slugger)$': 'babel-jest',

// "^.+\\.mjs$": "babel-jest",

'^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['next/babel'] }],
```

},

```
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "json", "node", "md"],

  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./setupTests.js'],

  testPathIgnorePatterns: [

//'<rootDir>/node_modules/', 

"<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(github-slugger)/)",

// '<rootDir>/.next/',

// '<rootDir>/setupTests.js',

  ],

};



.babelrc


  "presets": [

"@babel/preset-env",

"@babel/preset-react"

  ]
```

Please kindly help me. I'm trying to do this for 3 days and honestly feeling so lost.

I tried adding 'node:module' to my package.json

I tried remaining files from .js to .mjs

I tried changing many times my jest.config.js & .babelrc but to no success

Comment: Add a babel config with preset-env modules set to commonjs. Update your jest config transform to have your files run through babel-jest.

Comment: I added below to my .babelrc but still get import error.   {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": "commonjs"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}

Comment: Looks like you need to add `github-slugger` to the [`transformIgnorePatterns`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring).

Answer (score 0):

The relevant details indicate `github-slugger` is published using ESM.

```
Details:

/Users/alex/Desktop/test/tech-blog-web/node_modules/github-slugger/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { regex } from './regex.js'
                                                                                  ^^^^^^
```

You should transpile that dependency before running your tests by including it in your Jest config like

```js
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(github-slugger)/)']
```

See [`transformIgnorePatterns`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) for more details.